# Converting a decimal number into a Q3.4 fixed point representation

Tags: binary, fixed-point, ieee

How can I convert - 4,5_10 into the Q3.4 fixed point representation?

My suggestion would be:

4_10 = 100_2

0,5 * 2 = 1,0

0 * 2 = 0,0

Result: 0100 0010_2

Inverting the result to: 1011 1101_2

And adding +1 to the one's complement

= 1011 1110_2C (Two's complement)

Would that be right? I tried it on another way, but it I still get a different result.

Comment: e.g. if I calculate it this way: 4,5 * 2^2 = 18_10 and 18_10 = 00010010_2 inverting it to 11101101_2 and adding 1 it would be: 11101110_2C

Comment: 4.5_10=0100.1000 as 4=2^2=0100 and 0.5=2^-1=0.100. So 4.5=0100.1000 and -4.5=1011.1000

Comment: Thanks.I noticed that I've added the two zeros to:                                                                  0,5 * 2 = 1,0 ;
0 * 2 = 0,0          in the wrong order. It should have been 1000 and not 00100 because one reads from above to the bottom, right?